# How do I bulk rename albums in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I have an online subscription to a radio program that allows me to download past episodes. However when they are opened in iTunes the album name is set in the format Apr 01 2008. The problem is that there are thousands of these and I would like to change it to a better format such as 2008 01 Apr or even 2008 Apr 01. Is there any automatic way to change an mp3's metadata - or a program like a Better Finder Rename that can edit this iTunes metadata for the thousands of tracks that I have?

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [Doug's Applescripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) as a *great* resource to keep in mind for any future questions you might have. From it I found [the script that applies `sed` to the track names.](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=tracknameeditwithsed) Once you follow the instructions to install the script, put the following code in the popup box:

```
s/\([:alpha:]\)+ \([:digit:]+\) \([:digit:]+\)/\3 \1 \2/
```

N.B. This is actually the first time I've used `sed`, so I recommend testing this out on a few individual songs first.

(Also, if you don't have any programming experience, then it's likely that the Regular Expression above looked downright arcane. Don't worry! That's totally normal.)

Answer (score 5):

You should check out [Doug's Applescripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/). He's written a collection of scripts that will do most everything.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Doug's Script (the one that applies sed to track names) with this pattern:

```
s/\([:alpha:]*\)\ \([0-9]\{2\}\).\([0-9]\{2\}\).\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1 \4-\3-\2/
```

to rename stuff like `Charts 01.10.2013` to `Charts 2013-10-01`.

However if you want to use it for Albums and not for the Title, you have to modify the AppleScript and replace `name` with `album` in the line that contains the `sed` command

Comment: How does this differ or improve on Josh Tilles's answer?

Comment: mine is for the european date format